# From a backbone.js view and using Openlayers, how would i interact with the map from a openlayers event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, openlayers, backbone-views

I have a view that is and list of markers.  This list is displayed along the side of my map.

I have an onclick event that is fired when someone clicks on a marker name in the list.

Within this onclick event I need to interact with the map.

I am trying to get a certain layer on the map.  How do i interact with openlayers map from this event?

```
app.MarkerListView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $( '#markerListPanel'),

initialize: function(){

    //event setup
     $('#markerlist').on('click', 'a', function () {
         var layer = map.getLayersByName("Marker Layer");

    });
},

createMarkerList: function(json){
         //...some code here
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way is to associate a model with the information of the layer. Backbone offers just that. The views will be represantations of the same information. As the view is aware of its model, it is easy to create methods and event listeners that can respond to interaction from the map and the sidebar.

I used this approach before in an application and have been happy with the outcome.